# SQLCMD syntax to alter Login Properties and disable "Enforce Password expiration"

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am trying to create a SQLCMD script and run it as a Windows Batch file. Which will disable "Enforce Password expiration" for an existing Login Name in Microsoft SQL Server.

[image: Screenshot]

So I am not trying to create new login, but alter existing one.

This is what .sql script looks like for TestUser:

USE [master]
GO
ALTER LOGIN [TestUser] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON
GO

Thank you all.

Comment: FYI, if you do the action, and the click the Script button (instead of "OK"), it'll tell you what the SQL you're going to run is.

Comment: Great, that's one part of it, and a huge save in time. 
Now I have failed to phrase the question correctly. I need that as a batch file (I'm assuming it would utilize SQLCMD, so there is no need to login to SSMS).

I'll edit the question.

Comment: Save to file, `sqlcmd -i`. (Alternatively, remove all newlines and `USE master / GO` from the query and `-Q`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one-liner you can run from cmd:

```
echo ALTER LOGIN [TestUser] WITH CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF | sqlcmd -S localhost -E -d master
```

Replace localhost with your server and alternately specify SQL login info (-U and -P) instead of trusted login (-E) for a login that has admin privileges to change this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone.

with everyone's help I managed to create this line and it works perfectly for my needs:

```
sqlcmd -S (local)\sqlexpress -Q "ALTER LOGIN [TestUser] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON"
```